# Cant see NAVBAR Hamburger ICON, but it works

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

When I make the window smaller, I can still click on where the hamburger icon should be, and the dropdown drops and it works, but there is NO icon for the hamburger (aka the 3 little lines) any help would be awsome!

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">GroupWrites</a>
        </div>

         <!--Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse"  id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="/browse">Explore</a></li>
            <li><a href="/browse/new">Publish</a></li> 
            <li><a href="/library">Library</a></li>
            <li><a href="/about">How It Works</a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <% if(!currentUser){ %>
            <li><a href="/register">Create Account <i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="/login">Log In <i class="fa fa-user-circle"></i></a></li>
            <% } else { %>
            <li><a href="#">Signed In As <%= currentUser.username %></a></li>
            <li><a href="/logout">Log Out <i></i></a></li>
            <% } %>
            </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

CSS

```
body { font-family: comfortaa; padding-top: 90px; line-height: 1.75 }
.navbar{ background-color: #3c3d41; color: white; padding: 5px; }
.navbar li a:hover, 
.navbar li a:active { border-bottom: 2px solid white; background-color: #3c3d41; color: white ; }
.navbar-brand:hover,
.navbar-brand:active { border-bottom: 2px solid white; background-color: #3c3d41; color: white ; }
a { color: white; }
#button { background: rgb(100,149,237); color: white; }
```

That is my navbar code. It is in my header and everything works perfectly, I just cannot actually see the hamburger icon itself. Any help would be amazing. Please and thank you. Seems like something very easy that I quite cant put my finger on.

Comment: Use your browser element inspector to see the CSS applied to the icon. It's going to give you a good idea of what is happening.

Comment: Please provide css too.

Comment: @EmmaEarlKent 
body {
 font-family: comfortaa;
 padding-top: 90px;
 line-height: 1.75
}

.navbar{
  background-color: #3c3d41;
  color: white;
 padding: 5px;
}

.navbar li a:hover,
.navbar li a:active {
  border-bottom: 2px solid white;
  background-color: #3c3d41;
  color: white ;
}

.navbar-brand:hover,
.navbar-brand:active {
  border-bottom: 2px solid white;
  background-color: #3c3d41;
  color: white ;
}

a {
 color: white;
}

#button {
 background: rgb(100,149,237);
 color: white;
}

Comment: I've run into this issue before.  Look in your browsers dev tools at the *computed* CSS properties.  Verify the font matches the font used by the icon.  Then verify that the font file is being loaded by your browser correctly.  Your issue is either a) the element doesn't have the correct font, or b) the font isn't getting loaded (which can happen for a number of reasons).

Answer (score 0):

So I got it to work , by changing the class from "navbar navbar-fixed-top" to "navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" still not sure why this is though. With navbar-inverse my hamburger icon-bars display. So I just customized .navbar-inverse to my same colors and css as I wanted.